# pdf to chm handling libraries for python3

Tags: python, pdf, chm

I've tried to find a software for pdf to chm conversion to convert my pdf e-books to chm, but I ended up disappointed.

So, as a pythonian, I decided to create my own program to convert pdf files to chm, however, all pdf/chm libraries I found are python2 libraries.

Are there python 3 libraries to handle pdf/chm files?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Python 2, I just started with python 3 and stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write CHM, then afaik only Free Pascal (and therefore Delphi with minimal effort) has a  free CHM generator library.

All other tools use the Microsoft commandline tool behind the scenes.

For reading there is chmlib, I assume there is some python wrapper for it somewhere.